# How do I follow a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I *know* I can do this, but I just can't find the button...

How do I follow a tag?

Comment: If you don't see "subscribe" when hovering over the tag, make sure you are logged-in! (Yes, I'm ashamed to admit this has happened to me!)

Comment: Get an email whenever a question is asked: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'follow', but you can hover over the tag to get access to the *subscribe* and *rss* links, and you can also use *favorites* (accessible on the sidebar) to generate a collection of 'interesting' tags. You can also use the *ignored* feature to generate a collection of tags that you're not interested in (so they don't show, or at least don't show as prominently on the site for you.)

Thanks to Bill's note I just learned you can use the star in the tag-hover-popup to toggle your preference between *favorite*, *ignored* and *normal* (saving you from having to use the side forms).

Your second (now gone) question is a completely different question, and besides not being appropriate having two unrelated questions in one, the topic has been previously covered, should you care to search.

Comment: Note: When you hover over the tag, you can also click on the star to add it to your favorites.

Comment: wow, that's a well hidden feature

Comment: Cool, so how do you see a list of all tags you are following now?