# How do I know if I messed up a question beyond repair and should create a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've created a messy question on StackOverflow (could have been on any site) and just made it worse after people started commenting. The question got downvoted and my problem was left without a solution.

Should I edit the question completely or just create a new one? What aspects of the mess up I should take into consideration when deciding this?

Deleting the original question and creating a new one seems like... cheating somehow?

Comment: "Should I edit the question completely or just create a new one? " - You should absolutely NOT ask the same question again.  Asking the same question will just result in a question ban.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question Garners New Facet, Close ? Edit ? New Question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168709/question-garners-new-facet-close-edit-new-question)

Comment: @Ramhound the thing is: I messed the question up in the title and people gave me incorrect answers because they couldn't understand it.  Should I edit the title instead? Since it got downvoted, I'm afraid people would start to ignore it.

Comment: @Rob nooot exactly, since I already had all the info in the first place. I just messed it up because 1. English is not my first language 2. it was hard to explain my issue due to its complexity

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, the other question is much more complicated and about a changing technical specification.

Comment: 0923052323, we explain to new users that the comment you replied to is automatically generated by the system during a Review; usually we don't reply, especially to senior users. --- That is but one of many possible duplicates of your question, additional duplicates can come from review or be found in the right side column. --- You should always ensure that your question (and answers) are well written; you can edit the question above to ensure that no other duplicates it **but** now that it has an answer you must be careful not to make an edit that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YMMV,

> Deleting the original question and creating a new one seems like... cheating somehow?

It isn't cheating. But that's not the recommended course of action.

1. Check any thread by anyone who ever hit a [post ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-ban). They all say: "Try salvaging your posts by editing them into shape".
2. If you like badges notice there's [a positive/negative question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361614) that impacts your Curious/Inquisitive/Socratic badge awards.

In the above 2 scenarios deleting clearly counts against you. Depending on your rep and track-record this may range from having nearly no impact to significantly changing your participation.

3. Take care if posting a new overhauled version of the question without deleting the old one, there's still a chance someone might consider both questions similar enough and vote for closure as a self-duplicate. (Which would count towards aggravating the 2 former points.)

> The question got downvoted and my problem was left without a solution.

Edit it. That's enough for the downvoters to be able to reverse their vote. Some users might be [following your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661) and [tag watchers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121206) are also likely to not have read it yet, or revisit it if there's recent activity.

NOTE: In these cases it might be better to temporarily delete the question in order to calmly edit it - you can undelete it when you're done. (That way the post is kept out-of-view and temporarily protected from further downvotes and comments.)

Vote counts can auto-correct after edits. All things considered editing is still, probably, your best course of action.

Comment: You can't edit your own question while it's self-deleted, because spammers have abused it in the past. You'll have to edit your question in an external editor and then save the edit after undeleting.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog yeah exactly, edit/revise the question (outside the editor or in the sandbox).

Comment: Everything makes sense, but I still feel like editing the question to make it clearer would be pointless since it was already downvoted. It might be a misconception of mine that people "ignore" downvoted questions

Comment: @0923052323 for example [search by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) has a tab called "Active". After you edit the question gets bumped to the top. Downvoted questions (with recent activity) actually get a lot of attention, people check them to see what's wrong and if something needs to be done (like closing, editing, etc...)

Comment: @bad_coder I never looked at it this way. I guess this settles this up.